# Excel VBA - How to Find Last 24 Hours date from Today and Yesterday

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to all the Experts contributing to SO, who help newbie like me

I was given a CSV Dump and asked to automate a report

I'm using Excel VBA

There are 16 requirements / steps to complete that automates the Report
I was able to complete 14 out of them ( of course searching in SO and changing the code to my requirements !!! )

The final steps in the Macro involve Filters, I never wrote Filters through Code and this was new to me

Below was one on the requirement, which involves filters
after a lot of searching and debugging, I was able to code the below Procedure
and this works fine

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Requirement:
    Exclude rows contains the FDN  From the column CI Group Name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        Dim DataRange               As Range
        Dim Column_Number           As Integer



                ' Find the Data Range From where in Sheet [ Working WB ], I have to Select Data
                Call UnknownRange(WorkBook_02_Name, WorkBook_02_Sheet1_Name)

                    Set DataRange = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))



                        ' Set Reference to WorkBook_02
                        Set WorkBook_02 = GetWorkbookReference(WorkBook_02_Path_Office & "\" & WorkBook_02_Name)


                            ' Get the WorkSheet Name into Var
                            WorkBook_02_Sheet1_Name = WorkBook_02.Sheets(1).Name

                                With Workbooks(WorkBook_02_Name).Worksheets(WorkBook_02_Sheet1_Name)

                                    Workbooks(WorkBook_02_Name).Worksheets(WorkBook_02_Sheet1_Name).Activate

                                        ' Get the Required Column # from the Column Name
                                        Column_Number = ColumnName_To_ColumnNumber("CI")

                                            ' Remove Datum on Column [ CI ] having FDN
                                            'DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Column_Number, Header:=xlYes


                                            'Worksheets(WorkBook_02_Sheet1_Name).AutoFilterMode = True
                                            With DataRange
                                                DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=Column_Number, Criteria1:="=*FDN*"

                                                Set ExcludeRange = DataRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                                                    With ExcludeRange
                                                         'Remove Datum on Column [ CI ] having VDI
                                                        .EntireRow.Delete
                                                        '.Delete
                                                    End With

                                                Worksheets(WorkBook_02_Sheet1_Name).AutoFilterMode = False
                                            End With


                                End With


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ' --------------------------------------------------------
        Function ColumnName_To_ColumnNumber(ColumnName As String)
        ' --------------------------------------------------------

        '   Column Name to Column Number

            ColName = ColumnName
            Debug.Print Range(ColName & 1).Column

            ColumnName_To_ColumnNumber = Range(ColName & 1).Column

        ' --------------------------------------------------------
        End Function
        ' --------------------------------------------------------
        '
        '

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Request #1**

In the above code I'm using .Activate to activate the Worksheet
In SO i read that I have to avoid ( .select / .activate .... )
As the Workbook i'm using has Only Single Sheet, I can avoid .Activate in the above code

However, when I work on Multiple sheets, if I do NOT use .Activate, the Sheet which I need to work, will NOT get the Focus
So I'm not sure how to avoid .Activate

---

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Requirement:

Having last 24 hours date ( Yesterday 9 PM To today 9 PM) from the column F "Time Stamp"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Column F have Time Stamps
I am supposed to Filter out the Last 24 Hours from this Column

Here is the Sample of Column F

```
9/15/2014 7:33
9/15/2014 7:24
9/15/2014 7:21
9/15/2014 7:20
9/15/2014 6:43
9/15/2014 6:32
9/15/2014 6:25
9/15/2014 5:43
9/15/2014 5:30
9/15/2014 5:27
9/15/2014 4:56
9/15/2014 4:41
9/15/2014 4:28
9/15/2014 3:29
9/15/2014 3:29
9/15/2014 2:26
9/29/2014 19:22
9/29/2014 18:47
9/29/2014 18:42
9/29/2014 18:20
9/29/2014 18:05
9/29/2014 17:40
9/29/2014 17:36
9/29/2014 16:54
10/15/2014 10:07
10/15/2014 10:07
10/15/2014 10:07
10/15/2014 10:07
10/15/2014 10:07
10/15/2014 10:07
```

I have no clue how to code this, but I am thinking in the following steps:

Step #1
Find what is this year

Step #2
I have to find out what is Todays date and Yesterdays date, assign them to #2 variables

Step #3
Basing on Todays date, I have to find out how many hours are in that filter
If there are 24 entries then I am done, I have got all the 24 hrs
And the condition is [ Yesterday 9 PM to Today 9 PM ]

Step #4
Basing on Todays date, If there are less than 24 entries, then I have to look into Yesterdays date and start couting from it till it completes 24 hrs

(or)

### Avoid the filters and use pure VBA to acomplish the above #4 Steps on Column F

**Request #2**

Please help me out to find the 24 Hours Date, using Filters or by any other means

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Below the Recorded Macro
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub Last_24_Hours_()
'
' Last_24_Hours_ Macro
' Last_24_Hours_
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C6"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CM$38854").AutoFilter Field:=6, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(3, "10/14/2014 10:59:48", 3, _
        "10/14/2014 11:57:37", 3, "10/14/2014 12:58:39", 3, "10/14/2014 13:59:39", 3, _
        "10/14/2014 14:59:39", 3, "10/14/2014 15:59:42", 3, "10/14/2014 16:59:44", 3, _
        "10/14/2014 17:59:43", 3, "10/14/2014 18:59:44", 3, "10/14/2014 19:59:46", 3, _
        "10/14/2014 20:59:47", 3, "10/14/2014 21:59:49", 3, "10/14/2014 22:59:51", 3, _
        "10/14/2014 23:59:52", 2, "10/15/2014")
End Sub

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in Advance,

Chakri

9:08 AM 11/9/2014
Thanks Jeeped

Sorry for nor being clear. Yes there are dates that are before Now().

Please note that the CSV dump i have contains data till 15-Oct-2014 Only.

**Here is Manual Way I do, to collect the 24 hours from Column F:**

(1) I apply Autofilter.

(2) Put filter on Column F

(3) From the Filter I select Year 2014, under which I have #2 months available [ Sep and Oct ]

(4) In the current dump I have, Oct-15-2014 has 11 Entries [ i.e, 11 Hours ], 
     so I select [ 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 ]

(5) So, I got my 10 Hours and I have to get the remaining 24 - 11 = 13 hours,

(6) For the remaining 13 hours, I select, Oct-14-2014, leave the first 11 hours ( as I already have them from Oct-15-2014 ), 
     and start selecting values [ 11, 12 ,13, 14 ,15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 ]

So, from the above Manual procedure I do, Now() might not be helpful ( on the current CSV dump I have, as the Max dates are Oct-15 and Oct-14 )

However, the code you provided will be very helpful for Latest Dumps I get

So, how should the above manual procedure be coded to get the 24 hours from Oct-15 and Oct-14

Also, in your code, I am not sure if the Time Factor [  **( Yesterday 9 PM To today 9 PM)**  ] is followed or not

Thanks 
Chakri

Comment: @Jeeped, I edited my post, explaining the Manual procedure I do to get the 24 hours. Please let me know if I am clear in explaining what I want to accomplish

Comment: Hi, Once I apply an Auto Filter to Column F, which has data in the DateTime format [ 10/14/2014 23:59:52 ], Is there any option or code to find the Last Entry in the Filter List, or is there an option to find out the Last #2 Days, that is Today and Yesterday from the Filtered Data. Thanks Chakri

Answer (score 0):

This short snippet may be enough to get you started with the `.AutoFilter` property.

```
Dim rFilteredCells As Range, lCountFilteredCells As Long
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & (Now - 1), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Now
    'get a count of the visible cells
    lCountFilteredCells = Application.Subtotal(102, .Columns("F"))
    Debug.Print lCountFilteredCells
    'set a range object to the filtered cells
    Set rFilteredCells = .Offset(1, 6).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Debug.Print rFilteredCells.Address(0, 0)
    Set rFilteredCells = Nothing
    'turn .AutoFilter off
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

After filtering column F for datetimes within 24 hours, I've shown some quick methods of counting the visible datetimes and setting a range object to only the visible (i.e. *filtered*) cells.

It wasn't completely clear on whether you might have dates that were after *Now* but I've used a strict 24 hour 'window'.